# installing apk from another apk in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, air

is it possible to call another .apk file from the one that's installed, in **AS3/AIR**?

> i have an apk (developed in AIR 2.6) which would ask for user login, and only when all the requirements are correctly input into, user can get access or install the main game(which is another apk). i have surfed through many websites but could not get satisfying result (esp. for FLASH) though.

it would be great help if i could get any help or tutorial regarding my topic.

Answer (score 0):

Short answert is NO - you can't install another APK but you always can direct user to the another APK and ask him to install - user needs to permit from installs not from Play Store. Or you may have all within the same APK and allow access after credentials are verified succesfully - either way why would you like to have this?

Answer (score 0):

use this ANE https://github.com/jakehilton/PackageManagerANE to do so. you can call your .apk to start the installing process on your device.